# Powershell: Activate Permissive X-FRAME-OPTIONS Header

Tags: 2013, powershell, x-frame

I'm searching a way to activate the features Permissive X-FRAME-OPTIONS Header on my web application with powershell.
But i can't find it with Get-Feature. Here is the feature i want to change:

[image]

With the command

> get-spfeature | where-object {($*.CompatibilityLevel -eq 15) -and ($*.scope -eq "WebApplication")} | Sort-object displayname

I get:

[image]

Where do i need to search to find it and activate it?

Thank you.

Comment: This feature is not a standard feature but a custom one installed by a custom wsp solution in your farm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find it. The compatibility level was 14 and not 15. Weird because i thought that for sharepoint 2013, it was 15 and for 2010 it was 15. I understood it badly i presume. So:

> get-spfeature | where-object {($*.CompatibilityLevel -eq 14) -and ($*.scope -eq "WebApplication")} | Sort-object displayname | select displayname

Give me the:

> Ventigrate.Shared.PermissiveXFrameHeader_PERMISSIVEXFRAME